# Link to specific page in an iFrame from another page

Tags: jquery, iframe

I want to link to a specific page in an iframe from my home page. For example, on my home page I want to advertise a job opening within our company. The job applications process is controlled by a third part company, we currently just use an iFrame to their application system.

I want to advertise this job opening on our homepage and link directly into the job description within the iframe, bypassing the first couple of pages of the application system.

Is it possible to do this using jQuery ?

*EDIT*

Please note the iFrame is not on my home page is on separate careers.html page. So I want to link from my home page (index.html) to careers.html and then get a specific page within the iFrame.

Regards,
Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the iframe is already on your page?

Have the link run this code:

```
$('iframe#foo').attr('src','http://www.the-url.com');
```

Comment: Thanks, but the iframe is not on my home page, its on careers.html.

Comment: I passed the iframe page url in the link from my home page and then used your code above to redirect the iframe to the correct location. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

index.html has a link to careers.html. careers.html has an I frame on it. So you want to set the iframes target. too.

So you link on the home page needs to look like:

```
<a href="careers.html?iframe_targ=page_for_iframe.html">Click here</a>
```

careers.html the needs to have

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
  if(results == null)
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
  }
```

Above code adapted from [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

```
$('iframe#foo').attr('src', getParameter("iframe_targ"));
```